# Return average number of turns over 1000 times

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation, markov-chains

I'm relatively new to R and I've been set a project to simulate a game. I've designed the game and entered a code in which it will return the number of turns taken to win the game, however I'm stuck with how to simulate the game 1000 times and return the average, although it seems so simple, I just can't work it out.

The code to return how many turns it takes to win:

```
    s=seq(1:25)
    current=vector()
    current[1]=1
    gameon=1
    turns=1
    while(gameon==1)
    {
      current[turns+1]=sample(s,1,replace=TRUE,prob=w[current[turns],])
      turns=turns+1
      if (current[turns]==25)
      {
       gameon=0
      }
    }
```

The game code and transition matrix:

```
w = matrix(0, nrow=25, ncol=25)
for (i in 1:25)                      #RED   - 1,2 down 2     3,4 back 3      5,6 
stay
{                                    #AMBER - 1,2 down 1   3,4 back 2      5,6 
forward 1
  if (i == 4)                        #GREEN - 1,2 stay     3,4 forward 1   5,6 
forward 2
  {
    w[i, i+2] = 1/3
    w[i,i+1] = 1/3           # effects on a state with a GREEN pub
    w[i,i] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 6)
  {
    w[i,i] = 1/3
    w[i,i+1] = 1/3
    w[i,i+2] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 7)
  {
    w[i,i-3] = 1/3
    w[i,i-2] = 1/3          # effects on a state with an AMBER pub
    w[i,i+1] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 12)
  {
    w[i,i] = 1/3
    w[i,i+1] = 1/3
    w[i,i+2] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 16)
  {
    w[i,i-3] = 1/3
    w[i,i-2] = 1/3         # effects on a state with a RED pub
    w[i,i+1] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 15)
  {
    w[i,i-10] = 1/3
    w[i,i-3] = 1/3         # effects on a state with a RED pub
    w[i,i] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 18)
  {
    w[i,i] = 1/3
    w[i,i+1] = 1/3         # effects on a state with a RED pub
    w[i,i+2] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 21)
  {
    w[i,i-10] = 1/3
    w[i,i-3] = 1/3
    w[i,i] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i == 24)
  {
    w[i,i-10] = 1/3
    w[i,i-3] = 1/3                  #horrible square to be stuck on, cant win from 
this square.
    w[i,i] = 1/3
  }
  else if (i <= 19)
  {
    w[i, seq(i+1,i+6)] = 1/6
  }
  else if (i==20)
  {
    w[i,seq(i+1,i+4)] = 1/6                
    w[i,i+5] = 2/6
  }
  else if (i==22)
  {
    w[i,seq(i+1,i+2)] = 1/6
    w[i,i+3] = 4/6
  }
  else if (i == 23)
  {
    w[i,i+1] = 1/6
    w[i,i+2] = 5/6
  }
  else if (i == 25)
  {
    w[i,i] = 1 #game finished
  }

}
```

I believe a for loop would be best to use but I don't know how to set it up to return the average number of turns.